# How to set a user as a default user in chrome/chromium browser when I have multiple sign ins?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

Browsers chrome and chromium let more than one user sign in using their google accounts. How can one set a particular account as the default one?

Answer (score 1):

To Achieve this you need to **sign out off all Gmail accounts**.

For your **Primary** you need to **sign into it first.**

Then you **sign back into the rest**.

Close your Browser and your **account you signed in with first** will be the **Default**.

Easiest way Ive used.

Comment: My experience (Linux Mint 18.1; Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)) has been that it will consistently open into the most recently used account, regardless of which was created first.

Comment: This used to work, but has recently stopped working for me. Regardless of the order I log in as, if I have one of the users synced to Chrome/Chromium that is always used as the "default" user (`/0/` in the URL). I think it might be related to my browser version (`Chromium 73.0.3683.75`) as on another computer with an earlier version of Chrome, this answer still works.