# Changing the default user in Chrome

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I have 2 Google accounts - work and personal. Every time I open Chrome it uses my work account to remember browsing history etc. I find I have to switch user to get my home Chrome version with all my bookmarks etc. Can I change this to always start Chrome with my home Google account?

Comment: Are you using separate browser profiles or just the Google Multi-login?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to sign out of both of them, then sign into the account you want to be default **first** (so your home account), followed by signing into your other account(s). See also [this same question on SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/q/1068006/238753).